# iOS - Help me understand multiple targets and in-app upgrades/purchases

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, target, storekit

Ok guys, go easy on me please.  Ive been trolling this board for years and have gotten so much help I cant even begin to think where I would be without it.  So thanks for the years of help!

I have the typical scenario:
Free app and a paid app.  I released my free version a year ago and have just recently released my paid version.  My goal is to update my free version with the ability to upgrade to my paid version.  After researching this it seems as though my best option is to build 2 targets then use #ifdef to turn ON and OFF certain features I want to limit.

So I went ahead and duplicated my paid target, made all the needed plist changes and put in code like this...

```
#ifdef LITE_VERSION
    NSLog(@"Lite Version");
    [self loadAds];  
#endif
```

This works well and I now have a Lite target with ads and a paid target with no ads. (and some other features of course)

But now Im a bit confused where to go from here.
Do I use the StoreKit to link the upgrade button to my paid version?  If so, how?
Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

I know similar questions have been asked and answered but they all seemed to cover the programming portion of this but not what to do beyond that.

Thanks 
Merlin

Answer (score 0):

`#define` works at compile time, so it's useful if you want a single code base to create a separate versions of your app - for example a "free" version with ads or limited features, and a full "paid" version.

Here's how to add it:

- Create an additional target in your project (this will be the "free" version)
- in the compile options for your free app, under **Other C Flags**, add `-DFREE_VERSION`
- as in your original question, use defines to control what goes in the free/paid versions.

```
#ifdef FREE_VERSION
[self showAds];
#endif
```

Note: To enable users to purchase/unlock features at runtime (e.g. using StoreKit), you can't use the `#define` technique.